# Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converges absolutely, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n^p$ converges absolutely for $p>1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

Prove that if $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$$ converges absolutely, then $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n^p$$ converges absolutely for $p>1$

Please tell me if I can go from (1) to (2)

### Here's my proof:

Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converges absolutely. Then $$(1) \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \lvert \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} \rvert=L<1$$
Now, take $$(2)  \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left(\lvert \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} \rvert\right)^p=(L)^p<1$$ for $p>1$.

Then $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \lvert \frac{b_{n+1}^p}{b_n^p} \rvert=L^p<1$$ where $L^p <1$ also for all $p$. Thus, we have shown, with the ratio test, that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n^p$ converges absolutely when $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converges absolutely. $Q.E.D$

Comment: $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, but $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

Comment: Hence why I have for p>1. The original question also says for p>1. I will fix that.

Comment: For $n$ large enough, $|b_n|<1$, whence if $p\geqslant 1$ you can estimate the $p$-sum in terms of the original sum.

Comment: You should write $\sum |b_n|^p,$ because $b_n^p$ may not be defined if $b_n < 0.$

Answer (score 2):

Your conclusion (1) is wrong. For example, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ is converging absolutely, but your $L=1$.

**Hint:** If $p \geq 1$ then you can limit compare the two series.

**Hint 2:** If $p<1$ the statement is not true, as $a_n=\frac{1}{n^\frac{1}{p}}$ shows. Next time it would be a good idea to state the **entire** problem, and not leave things out, because they may * be important:

*may usually means must, because otherwise they would not be included in the problem ;)

Comment: Why does my L equal 1?

Comment: @clairaut $$L= \lim_n \frac{\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}=\lim_n\frac{n^2}{n^2+2n+1} \,.$$ And always remember that if something is stated in the problem, it should be important for the problem. If it is not, why would the problem add a random non-important thing? ;)

Comment: I have no idea where you're getting at. The definition of the ratio test is: If \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \lvert \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} \rvert=L<1, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converges absolutely.

Comment: I'm not sure how to format this in a comment

Comment: @clairaut Yes, but the CONVERSE is not true. In (1) you are using the converse of the ratio test, not the ratio test.

Comment: If I'm using the limit comparison test, that assures they both converge, but can I say they both converge absolutely too since my original statement says b_n converges absolutely?

Comment: @clairaut You can use the LCT for $\sum|b_n|$ and $\sum|b_n|^p$ ;)